# Cannot find symbol error in my minimum absolute difference pairs algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, greedy

Below is my implementation of the minimum absolute difference pairs algorithm.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Greedy{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int A[]={4,1,8,7};
        int B[]={2,3,6,5};
        Arrays.sort(A);
        Arrays.sort(B);
        int minDiff=0;
        for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++){
            minDiff+=Math.abs(A[i]-B[i]);

        }
        System.out.println("minDiff absolute diff ="+ minDiff);
    }
}
```

This gives me the error below, however:

```
Greedy.java:120: error: cannot find symbol
        Arrays.sort(A);
              ^
  symbol:   method sort(int[])
  location: class Arrays
Greedy.java:121: error: cannot find symbol
        Arrays.sort(B);
              ^
  symbol:   method sort(int[])
  location: class Arrays
2 errors
```

Can anyone identify the error in the code and provide a solution?

Comment: Looks weird to me. [That method exists,](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int%5B%5D)) and your import is correct.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this.

Comment: [I cannot reproduce either.](https://ideone.com/Oh2770) @trincot

Comment: Do you have a nearby class named "Arrays.java"?